# Magento2 paypal return URL

Tags: magento2, paypal-pro

What url should I be using to redirect my customers back to the site after they have paid with paypal?

Comment: This functionality is already there in magento so no need to do anything.

Comment: but in paypal I have to put a redirect url

Comment: Yes Magento already set return URL by default to success page.

Comment: You only need to create API details like API username, API password, API signature from PayPal account and add those to Magento backend return url cancel URL etc will be done by Magento itself.

Comment: So the "Auto Return for Website Payments" is just not required at all, if I turn it on I need to add a url.